# divide by zero interruption error "using float variables"

Tags: c, interrupt, divide-by-zero

Coding with C, (dev c++)
I'm using :

```
void h(int x)
{
    printf("error devide by zero");
}

signal(SIGFPE, h);
x = a / 0;
printf("%d", x)
```

---

it works fine with `int a, x;`
But when I'm using `float a, x;` the error message is :`"#INF "` 
Someone told me that i can interrupt with assembly , other told me that i must interrupt the BIOS,  but no solutions given

Comment: Floating-point division by zero doesn't cause an exception by default.

Comment: I assume that, by "error message", you actually mean that `printf` outputs `#INF`?

Comment: Yes i mean that mr.Cody , exactly :#INF00

Comment: That's because floating-point values have a representation for "infinity" and don't need to raise an exception. It is unclear what your actual question is. You are *wanting* to get an exception? Why don't you just add code that checks for a zero divisor?

Comment: I'm not trying to do "if (b ==0) printf(" can t divide by zero);" ... I want to interrupt it , hardware interruption

Comment: The question you're still refusing to answer is *why*? Hardware interrupts are extremely slow and cause all sorts of problems when running under an operating system. Why would you ever want to do this when you can handle it the *correct* way, with a simple check?

Comment: Because i want to :)

Answer (score -2):

The [Floating-Point environment](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fenv) defines whether exceptions are generated for divide-by-zero. Unless you explicitly turn it on or off, what behaviour you get is not defined.

Also, you are using the h function itself as a signal handler. When the signal is raised, this leads into an endless loop.

Comment: No, `h` is just `void h(int x){
printf("error devide by zero");}`.

Comment: I said it works fine if i do x=5/3; for example, also x= 5/0; "int"